# PHP - Simple script for image compression with pngquant

Tags: php, image, optimization, compression, pngquant

:) i found this 1 line of code in another post which successfully compresses the image using pngquant. the thing is, it outputs the optimised image with a different name (obviously to preserve the original).

im trying to find a way to:

a) add a minimum quality parameter of 60
b) use an if/else statement to to allow the user to choose to overwrite the existing file or output a new optimised image (of a user specified name)

thank you! ntlri - not to long read it

```
<?php system('pngquant --quality=85 image.png'); ?>
```

so what i have tried is the following.. for some reason the single quotes need to be double quotes to parse the variables correctly..

```
<?php

$min_quality = 60; $max_quality = 85;

$keep_original = 'dont_keep';

if ($keep_original == 'keep') {

    $image_name = 'image.png';

    $path_to_image = 'images/' . $image_name;

    $new_file = 'image2.png';

    $path_to_new_image = 'images/' . $new_file;

    // don't know how to output to specified $new_file name
    system("pngquant --quality=$min_quality-$max_quality $path_to_image");

} else {

    $image_name = 'image.png';

    $path_to_image = 'images/' . $image_name;

    // don't know if you can overwrite file by same name as additional parameter
    system("pngquant --quality=$min_quality-$max_quality $path_to_image");

    // dont't know how you get the name of the new optimised image
    $optimised_image = 'images/' . $whatever_the_optimised_image_is_called;

    rename($optimised_image, $image_name);

    unlink($optimised_image);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

from the docs of [this program](https://github.com/pornel/pngquant) :

> The output filename is the same as the input name except that\n\ it
>   ends in \"-fs8.png\", \"-or8.png\" or your custom extension

so , for this question:

> ```
> // don't know how to output to specified $new_file name
> system("pngquant --quality=$min_quality-$max_quality $path_to_image");
> ```

to choose a new name, assume you are compress image `name.png` :

```
--ext=_x.png
```

this will create new image called `name_x.png`

so , your `$new_file` would be just a suffix ,

```
$new_file = '_x.png'; // to choose new file name name_x.png
```

---

> // don't know if you can overwrite file by same name as additional
>   parameter

as mentioned in the program docs , the new file name will be suffixed by either `-fs8.png` or `-or8.png` , so you may rename the file which will produced with this suffix , **OR** simply set the `--ext` option to : `.png` and this will append to the original file

```
--ext=.png
```

for more details, check [the repository](https://github.com/pornel/pngquant)

Comment: apologies for choosing my answer, i will definitely read the repository next time

Comment: it's okey , but the solution your wrote -as i think and understood from the program docs- will alway overwrite on the original image

Answer (score 1):

i spoke to pornel whos the chappie that developed pngquant. its actually a lot simpler than all that i wrote that before...

! important - it is very important to use escapeshellarg() else people can take over your server by uploading a file with a special filename apparently.

```
$image_name = 'image.png';

$target_file = 'images/' . $image_name;

$existing_image = 'image.png'; // image already on server if applicable

$keep = 'keep';

$target_escaped = escapeshellarg($target_file);

if ($keep == 'keep') {

    // process/change output file to image_compressed.png keeping both images
    system("pngquant --force --quality=70 $target_escaped --ext=_compressed.png");

    $remove_ext = substr($newFileName, 0 , (strrpos($newFileName, ".")));

// $new_image is just the name (image_compressed.png) if you need it    
$new_image = $remove_ext . '_compressed.png';

    // remove old file if different name
    if ($existing_image != $newFileName) {

    $removeOld = '../images/' . $existing_image; 

    unlink($removeOld);

    } // comment out if you want to keep existing file

} else {

    // overwrite if file has the same name
    system("pngquant --force --quality=70 $target_escaped --ext=.png");

    // remove old file if different name
    if ($existing_image != $newFileName) {

    $removeOld = '../images/' . $existing_image; 

    unlink($removeOld);

    }

    $new_image = $newFileName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to override same name use this command

```
pngquant.exe --ext=.png --force input.png
```

so the output name will remain input.png